# How to see stack trace by pointer

Tags: c++, c

I have the only pointer to some allocated memory, can I get a stack trace in the code by that pointer?

I know how to get a stack trace from a method, but what if I catch an exception in another method - can I get a stack trace?

Comment: A pointer is just a variable holding a memory address. Why do you expect to be able to get a stack trace from that?

Comment: I do not know at all - just asked if it is possible because in windbg I can get a stack trace for the specific memory block

Comment: There is no guarantee that the stack and heap are in the same memory segment.  I recommend writing an {inline} assembly language function that returns the value of the stack pointer.  You'll have to figure out where the frames are in the stack.

Answer (score 1):

For best results, compile *without* optimization.

Under `gcc` [and *maybe* `clang`], you can use: `__builtin_frame_address` and `__builtin_return_address`. See `man gcc` for details [or just websearch for them].

You can also look at `getcontext`. It documents the `ucontext_t` struct and the `mcontext_t` struct.

Also, by using `sigaction` [with `SA_SIGINFO`], your signal handler can receive a pointer to a `siginfo_t` and a pointer to a `ucontext_t`.

In the past, I've been able to use combinations of the above to generate a stack trace from a signal handler (see `man 7 signal` for details on what functions you can safely call from a signal handler).

I was even able to coerce multiple threads to do this, usually, by sending a signal to the individual threads and each handler would dump the stack [with register values] for its given thread stack.

---

It helps to know *what* you want to achieve (e.g. debugging).

Normally, one uses an external `ptrace` based program (e.g. `gdb` or `strace`) to get information.

Or, you can instrument your code with debug `printf` calls to get a detailed list of who called what, with what values, etc.

For really tough debug issues, you may be able to write your own custom `ptrace` program, that your target program is aware of, and, they can work together to solve the problem.

Or, some combination of all of the above.

Answer (score 0):

> In computing, a stack trace (also called stack backtrace or stack traceback) is a report of the active stack frames at a certain point
>   in time during the execution of a program.

It will allow you to track the sequence of function calls and the list of stack frames of the functions that you called. A pointer variable has nothing to do with stack trace. It just holds an address.